# SQL sub query logic

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate values in a column called Peak, but I need to apply different calculations dependant on the 'ChargeCode'.

Below is kind of what I am trying to do, but it results in 3 columns called Peak - Which I know is what I asked for :)

Can anyone help with the correct syntax, so that I end up with one column called Peak?

```
Use Test

Select  Chargecode, 
    (SELECT 1 Where Chargecode='1') AS [Peak],
    (SELECT 1 Where Chargecode='1242') AS [Peak],
    Peak*2 AS [Peak],
    CallType 

from Daisy_March2014
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a `case` statement.  I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Select  Chargecode, 
        (case when chargecode = '1'
              when chargecode = '1242' then 2
              else 2 * Peak
         end) as Peak,
        CallType
from Daisy_March2014;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost it - but I need to be able to specify different values for different ChargeCodes: so something like: (case when chargecode in ('1') then 1 else (case when chargecode in ('1264') then 2 else Peak*2 end) as Peak, - But that doesn't work. How should I go about nesting case when? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Gordon, I have marked you response as Answered. Here is the final working code:

```
(case when chargecode in ('1') then 1 when chargecode in ('1264') then 2 else Peak*2 end) as Peak,
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it depends on your charge code, I'm going to make a wild assumption that this might be an ongoing thing where new charge codes / rules could be added.  Why not store this as metadata either in the charge code table or in a new table?  You could generate the initial data with this:

```
SELECT ChargeCode,
       Multiplier
INTO ChargeMeta
FROM (  
        Select 1 AS ChargeCode,
               1 AS Multiplier
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 1242 AS ChargeCode,
               1 AS Multiplier
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ChargeCode,
               2 AS Multiplier
        FROM Daisy_March2014
        WHERE ChargeCode NOT IN (1,1242) 
) SQ
```

Then just join to your original data.

```
SELECT a.ChargeCode,
       a.Peak*b.Multiplier AS Peak
FROM Daisy_March2014 a
JOIN ChargeMeta b
    ON a.ChargeCode = b.ChargeCode
```

If you do not want to maintain all charge code multipliers, you could maintain your non-standard ones, and store the standard one in the SQL.  This would be about the same as a case statement, but it may still add benefit to store the overrides in a table.  At the very least, it makes it easier to re-use elsewhere.  No need to check all the queries that deal with Peak values and make them consistent, if ChargeCode 42 needs to have a new multiplier set.

If you want to store the default in the table, you could use two joins instead of one, storing the default charge code under a value that will never be used.  (-1?)

```sql
SELECT a.ChargeCode,
       a.Peak*COALESCE(b.Multiplier,c.Multiplier) AS Peak
FROM Daisy_March2014 a
LEFT JOIN ChargeMeta b ON a.ChargeCode = b.ChargeCode
LEFT JOIN ChargeMeta c ON c.ChargeCode = -1
```